# airflow 1.10.10 behind Nginx Proxy: Oauth Redirect URL http instead of https

Tags: nginx, flask, oauth, airflow, kubernetes-ingress

I am deploying Airflow 1.10.10 on Kubernetes using the official Helm Chart (v.7.0.0) but I am running into issues with Oauth.

**Here's my setup:**

- Airflow Webserver with RBAC enabled. Airflow uses Flask Appabuilder in this case.
- Server runs behind an Nginx reverse proxy that does https termination.
- I try to authenticate against an Azure AD tenant using OAuth

**my problem**
- When I try to login with the Microsoft account I get the error message "The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application". 
- The error is caused by Airflow setting the redirect URL to http://airflow.example.com/oauth_authorized/azure instead of http**S**://airflow.example.com/oauhth_authorized/azure

**what I think the issue is**

Since nginx sends http requests to Flask, flask generates an http url for the redirect url instead of https. 
So from what I understand, I need to find a way to tell Airflow/Flask that it should use https to generate the redirect URL instead.

**What I tried:**

I have two angles of attack:

**1. setting the base URL to https explicitly in the webserver_config.py file**

I tried putting environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https' in the config file, but I get a "environ is not defined" error. 
Can I even set this in in the config.py file? What would I need to import for it to work?

**2. Setting proxy headers in nginx**

I tried to set multiple headers in Nginx using Kubernetes annotations, my current settings are:

```
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
```

I also tried to set

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

but this leads to all traffic being redirected to a comma separated list of domains

```
airflow.example.com,airflow.example.com
```

which obviously does not work.

I based these settings on the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups).

The rest of the Nginx config is the default of the official Nginx ingress controller I have running in my cluster.

Does anybody have an idea what the issue could be? Are my two angles of attack valid or is there a third one that I am missing?

Thanks a lot, any help is appreciated!

Comment: able to solve it? If so please post your solution.

Comment: Unfortunately no. We ended up using Google as our auth provider, which worked. I might play around with these things again soon, I will post an answer if I figure it out.

Comment: Had the same issue. I added this env variable and it worked for me `AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__ENABLE_PROXY_FIX: "True"`

Comment: kirancodify suggestion worked for me.